# Making new columns based on rows in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

| Station | Day | Precip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | w |
| A | 2 | x |
| B | 1 | y |
| B | 3 | z |

And I need to create a new data frame with the values in the Day column as the new column headers:

| Station | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | w | x |  |
| B | y |  | z |

I tried subsetting, summarizing, and then merging.

```
df1 <- subset(df, DAY == "1")
df2 <- subset(df, DAY == "2")
df3 <- subset(df, DAY == "3")

df1 <- df1 %>% group_by(STATION) %>% summarise(DAY_1 = sum(Precip))
df2 <- df2 %>% group_by(STATION) %>% summarise(DAY_2 = sum(Precip))
df3 <- df3 %>% group_by(STATION) %>% summarise(DAY_3 = sum(Precip))

df_grouped <- merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE)
df_grouped <- merge(df_grouped, df3, all = TRUE)
```

This does what I want, but I'm sure there's probably an easier way. I would greatly appreciate any thoughts. Thank you!

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = Day, values_from = Precip)` should do. See the linked FAQ for other methods and discussion.

Comment: @GregorThomas thank you so much! Exactly what I needed.